# Invoke Facebook Share Code from php once the user rates any item

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to implement a feature where once the user gives a rating to any item, Facebook share window should open by default.

Normally, I use the following social share code:

But I don't want the user to press share button to invoke the dialog box.

Is there a way to automatically invoke this FB share box using the above script by passing some arguments?

e.g. http://kindheartz.com/gallery/image/1-weds-trust-madurai#fwgallerytop

In the gallery when the user rates the image, I want the FB share box to pop up by default.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to load facebook Javascript SDK into your page

> The Facebook SDK for JavaScript doesn't have any standalone files that
>   need to be downloaded or installed, instead you simply need to include
>   a short piece of regular JavaScript in your HTML that will
>   asynchronously load the SDK into your pages. The async load means that
>   it does not block loading other elements of your page

To load the facebook javascript SDK put this code right after your `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{your-app-id}',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Remember to replace `{your-app-id}` by your **APP ID**, if you don't have any app you can create on here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

When your done and check if the Javascript SDK is being loaded properly, just add this piece of code into the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#YOUR_RATING_BUTTON", function(){
  var id= $(this).data('id');
  var photo= $(this).data('photo');
  var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: '{The link you want to share}',
    picture: '{the url of the photo you want}',
    name: '{The name of the link attachment}',
    description: '{The description of the link (appears beneath the link caption). If not specified, this field is automatically populated by information scraped from the link, typically the title of the page}',
    display: 'popup'
  };

  function callback(response) {
    //do something with callback
    if (response && response.post_id) {
     alert('Thank you for sharing this rating.');
    } else {
      alert('Rating was not shared.');
    }
  }

  FB.ui(obj, callback);
});
</script>
```

You can read more about Javascript SDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) and you can read more about Facebook Feed Dialog [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui)

Comment: Thats really great..I will try this for sure..the working demo will definitely help

Comment: I used this to invoke FB share : https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={Insert URL to be shared here}     . It worked for me

Comment: Yes it works, but keep in mind that you can't personalize the sharing, like the title, the image, etc since the sharer grabs that info through the og tags from the URL to be shared and also you can't find if the user really shared or pressed the cancel button. But if you are ok with that than sharer.php is the right solution for you